# Python Pygame Minesweeper game

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make the minesweeper game but I have seen this method to store a grid in a list.
how do I make a list inside a list that looks like my grid, For example:

```
list = 
[[x,y],[x,y][x,y],[x,y][x,y],[x,y]
[x,y],[x,y][x,y],[x,y][x,y],[x,y]
[x,y],[x,y][x,y],[x,y][x,y],[x,y]]
```

My code now is that all the grid is in one list([] and not [][])
I'm kinda new to programming in python so I'm not good at it. Hoping to get help and to solve this as fast as possible, Thank You all!

My code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.math import Vector2
import random

pygame.init()
HEIGHT = 800
WIDTH = 800
tile_size = 100

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Grid:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pGrid = [Vector2(0, 0)]
        for num in range(0, int(WIDTH/tile_size)):
            for num2 in range(0, int(HEIGHT/tile_size)):
                if(not(num == 0 and num2 == 0)):
                    self.pGrid.append(Vector2(num2*tile_size, num*tile_size))
    def make_grid(self):
        for line in range(0, int(WIDTH/tile_size)):
            pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (0, line*tile_size), (WIDTH, line*tile_size))
            pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (line * tile_size, 0), (line*tile_size, HEIGHT))

grid = Grid()
#def bomb_found():
    #bomb = pygame.image.load('Images/Bomb.png')
    #bomb = pygame.transform.scale(bomb, (100, 100))

bomb = pygame.image.load('Images/Bomb.png')
bomb = pygame.transform.scale(bomb, (100, 100))

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    screen.fill((175, 215, 70))
    grid.make_grid()
    #bomb_found()
    screen.blit(bomb, grid.pGrid[20])
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list for the column before the inner loop and add the `Vector2` objects to this list. Add the column list to the grid after the inner loop:

```py
class Grid:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pGrid = []
        for col in range(WIDTH//tile_size):
            column = []
            for row in range(HEIGHT//tile_size):
                column.append(Vector2(col * tile_size, row * tile_size))       
            self.pGrid.append(column)
```

The same using [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
class Grid:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pGrid = [[Vector2(c*tile_size, r*tile_size) for r in range(HEIGHT//tile_size)] for c in range(WIDTH//tile_size)]
```

The first subscription returns a column and the second subscription returns an item in the column (a row in the column). e.g.:

```py
col = 3 # 4th column
row = 2 # 3rd row
screen.blit(bomb, grid.pGrid[col][row])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehensions for easily creating a nested array of successive integer values.

```
w, h = 3, 4
[[(i, j) for j in range(h)] for i in range(w)]

#result
[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)],
 [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
 [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]]
```